# Calculating conditional probability with tree diagram

Tags: probability

Given this tree diagram: (rather poor quality sorry)
[image]

How can I find $P[R|G']$? I'm really struggling with this question and only managed to find $P(G) = 0.2327$ from dividing $74$ by the total of $G + NG = 318$. I apologize if the context of this question is crucial in finding this problem, if so please comment on that.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by $G'$, as opposed to $G$ ? Is it the same as $NG$ ?

Comment: The complement of G which is found by 1 - 0.2327 = 0.7673.

Comment: Main problem is I'm not sure how to find P(R) from that tree diagram alone.

Comment: P(R|NG) is just 0.29, isn't it?

Comment: Right, I got confused by the figures of G and NG.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewDaly. The value $P(R|NG) = 0.29$ can be directly read from the picture. And you were also wondering about $P(R)$, and that can be calculated from
$$
P(R) = P(R|G)P(G) + P(R|NG)P(NG) = 0.42\cdot \frac{74}{74+244} + 0.29 \cdot \frac{244}{74+244}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both $G'$ and $NG$ both mean the complement of $G$, your diagram seems to contain the answer:
$$
P(R|G')=.29.
$$
If you also need the probability of $R$ it is
$$
P(R)
=P(R|G)\times P(G) + P(R|G')\times P(G')
=.42\times {74\over 74+244} + .29\times {244\over 74+244}
=.320252
$$
(assuming this is the correct way of getting $P(G)$ from your notation).